# setonclicklistner is not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i am new to kotlin i was trying to make a bmi app from a course i binded the view and every thing is running fine but i think my onclicklistner is not working
below is my code can anyone check and see what is wrong

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        if(binding.weightEditText.text.isNotEmpty() && binding.heightEditText.text.isNotEmpty()) {
            binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener {
                val weight = binding.weightEditText.text.toString().toFloat()
                val height = binding.heightEditText.text.toString().toFloat()
                val myBMI = weight / (height * height)
                binding.bmiValue.text = myBMI.toString()

                if (myBMI < 18.5) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.underweight)
                } else if (myBMI >= 18.5 && myBMI < 24.9) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.healthy)
                } else if (myBMI >= 24.9 && myBMI < 29.9) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.overweight)
                } else if(myBMI>29.9) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.obesity)
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Add the asked field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your activity is created, your edit text is probably empty. so callback of click not set for your button.
You need to check the `editText` into the `clickListener` callback.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)                
        binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener {
            if(binding.weightEditText.text.isNotEmpty() && binding.heightEditText.text.isNotEmpty()) {

                val weight = binding.weightEditText.text.toString().toFloat()
                val height = binding.heightEditText.text.toString().toFloat()
                val myBMI = weight / (height * height)
                binding.bmiValue.text = myBMI.toString()

                if (myBMI < 18.5) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.underweight)
                } else if (myBMI >= 18.5 && myBMI < 24.9) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.healthy)
                } else if (myBMI >= 24.9 && myBMI < 29.9) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.overweight)
                } else if(myBMI>29.9) {
                    binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.obesity)
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Add the asked field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```